# How can I import custom element which is angular component without importing script tag in HTML?

Tags: angular

I've already done with the:
https://www.techiediaries.com/custom-elements-shadow-dom/

For the last step, It work fine for me.
but I want to know how to import it in angular project that is not importing script tag in index.html (e.g. from node_modules) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can import many external library in angular via `npm install --save <nameOfLibrary>`. This library will be place in the "node_modules" directory and will be known throw your package.json. This is for all the EXTERNAL libraries. When you'll upload your code on git, you won't upload the node_modules, because those externals libraries are public, there is no need to upload.

Now when you are creating a component in your angular project, you got two ways to call it.

1. First, like you said, with the HTML tag `<app-contact-form></app-contact-form>`
   (the name og the tag come from :

   `@Component({
     selector: 'app-contact-form',
     templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
   })`

   2. with a routing in the module: many website explain it. One exemple : https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/8104/angular-router-tutorial